# Kibana -> How to visualize endpoints popularity?

Tags: kibana

Given an api with two endpoints

```
/api/v3/left/{id}

/api/v3/right/{id}
```

How do I tell Kibana to show me the ranking of requests by

```
/api/v3/left/

/api/v3/right/
```

So that I get a visualization of two lines with a number of requests for each bucket?